# Deprotonation of 2- and 3-methylquinoline

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds

Why are there many examples of 2-methylquinolines being treated with a base then an electrophile but none of the corresponding reaction with 3-methylquinolines? Does this have to do with the charge not being stabilised for the 3-methylquinoline?

Comment: what you want to say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in contrast to 3-methylquinoline, the methyl group of 2-methylquinoline (**1**) is easily deprotonated by potassium ethoxide.

[image: anion of 2-methylquinoline]

The anion has been examined by NMR spectroscopy ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1246/cl.1975.717)), but its use in synthesis was reported long before. There's an article (in German) in *Chem. Ber.*, **1909**, *42*, 1140 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cber.190904201182)) where the reaction of 2-methylquinoline with diethyloxalate is described.